# Configuring and making: source, test and doc

Tags: linux, makefile, autotools, configure

I'm trying to create a configure script for building the source, tests and docs. The folders are the following:

- src
- test

And the docs I want to generate are coming from the source, processed by Doxygen.

I want to be able to do, after running the configure script, the following:

```
$ make  // to compile the source

$ make test // to compile the tests

$ make run_test <test_name> // to run an specific test

$ make doc // to run Doxygen and generate the documentation in a folder called "doc"
```

What do I need to perform these? I'm studying the Autotools documentation but I haven't found the way to perform this.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, in order to perform test, I'm using Googletest & Googlemock frameworks, which means that configuration script should check for the libgmock existence along with passing appropriates flags to Makefile in tests.

Comment: Apart from looking at how other packages using autotools, there's a good guide [here](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/books/autotools_a_guide_to_autoconf_automake_libtool).

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777301/extend-the-makefile-to-generate-a-library-and-documentation-with-doxygen>